# IE11 is not saving anything to appCache

Tags: internet-explorer-11, html5-appcache

I'm making an offline version of a presentation site for a client and have some issues getting it to work in IE11. It's the first time I'm working with AppCache, btw.

On the page there's a button to save the presentation for offline use. When pressed I first generate a new manifest file which is used on two pages which needs to be available offline. Here's an example:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 12-7-2016 09:30

# Common cached entries
/lib/tslib/ts.js
/lib/tslib/selector.js
/lib/ilscript.js
/lib/compatibility.js
/lib/tangora.public.imagerotator.js
/lib/snippethandlers.js
/setup/site.css
/lib/tangora.public.layout.js
/lib/tangora.public.list.js
/setup/clientscript.js
/html/lsig_toolbox.js
/lib/ajax.js
/media/system/lsig_toolbox_icon_home.png
/media/system/lsig_toolbox_icon_logout.png
/media/system/lsig_toolbox_body_bg_grey_black.png
/media/site_top_presentations.jpg
/media/system/lsig_toolbox_nav1_active_bg_black.png
/media/system/lsig_toolbox_presentations_date_bg.png
/media/system/lsig_toolbox_slide_number_bg.png
/media/system/lsig_toolbox_btn_bg_back.png
/media/system/lsig_toolbox_btn_bg_show.png
/setup/dialog_close_outlined.png
/setup/1x1.gif
/lib/tslib/tdom.js
/lib/tslib/terrorhandler.js
/lib/tslib/tbrowser.js
/lib/lightbox.js
/lib/animation.js
/setup/layout34/generic.css
/setup/layout34/master.css
/setup/layout34/TBF0DC2CGCB5H/navigation1.css
/setup/layout34/TBF0DC2CGGB5L/navigation1.css
/setup/layout34/TBF0DC2CGCB5H/navigation.css
/setup/layout34/TBF0DC2CGGB5L/navigation.css
/lib/BusyView.js

# Additional cached resources
/media/system/lsig_toolbox_document_icon_pdf.png
/ref.aspx?action=show&id=9155
/media/lsig_tools/imagegenerator/95x0/Ceasar_Salad.png
/ref.aspx?action=show&id=9372
/media/lsig_tools/imagegenerator/95x0/Potatopie_with_quark.png
/media/lsig_tools/imagegenerator/0x755/upscale(false)/Potatopie_with_quark.png
/media/lsig_tools/imagegenerator/95x0/Artisan_quark_ice-cream.png
/media/lsig_tools/imagegenerator/0x755/upscale(false)/Artisan_quark_ice-cream.png

FALLBACK:
/ /Saved-presentations

NETWORK:
*
```

Then I create two hidden iframes with the two pages with this manifest file in the html tag. I then wait for the updateready or cached events and removes the two iframes again afterwards.

The checking and progress events are fired and lastly the cached event for both pages and the console also tells that it is creating AppCache with the manifest but nothing is saved. When I go offline it just says "No internet connection".

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. One of the files I save locally was serving a pdf file with the header `Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf` and apparently this made IE11 fail silently. No error event was fired.

My workaround is to save the pdf file in app cache and adding the URL which served the file to the fallback section so when the user requests the URL they get the pdf.